# Is it possible to create an install disk/iso that will essentially create a clone of my custom kernel build

Tags: linux, installation, centos, iso-image

I have a custom kernel running on a CentOS 6.4 server with multiple packages, programs, and device drivers installed. I need to setup several other servers with the same configuration all across the board. I have a pxe server setup and running (with kickstart files) to automate the basic install from a standard CentOS iso, but I still have to do the kernel patch after install. I have it pseudo automated with the kickstart file, but still requires user input halfway through. Is there any way to create a new installable iso that will use the exact config of my patched system, and if so, how?

Comment: I just have to mention NixOS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is for a lab where we use specific OS's, mainly CentOS. From what I could tell at first glance NixOS is a research project and not really suitable for us. Plus, I really would like to be able to do this on other OS's like RHEL, Fedora, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about Ansible/Puppet/Chef? Each of those fully automates system tasks like the one you require.

Alternatively an idea that comes to mind, is making a personal repository in one of your servers, containing all the packages you require and configure yum to pull from there all packages at the first update

Answer (score 0):

You could also use clonezilla, to clone the whole finalized image to the target machine.

You can setup a clonezilla server.

Use pxe boot

1. PXE the master select save-image and etc
2. switch to multicast mode (although you can unicast)
3. Select the number of clients to wait for, or time
4. PXE boot all the clients (restore-image) and wait for completion

Comment: Can you perhaps give a rough idea of how to do so? (this A popped up in the *low quality posts* review queue, for what it's worth)